# python script to create user account from txt file

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to learn to program. I need help to loop users from the login.txt file into this subprocess. any help would be appreciated.

```
with open("login.txt",'r') as file:
#reading each line
for line in file:

    #reading each word
      for word in line.split():
         subprocess.run(['useradd',input=word , shell=True])
```

```
cat login.txt

test01

test02

test03

test04
```

getting this error:
File "loginscript.py", line 11
subprocess.run(['useradd',input=word , shell=True ])
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?  If this code is not working as expected, please give details.  Are you getting errors, or incorrect results?

Comment: This code gives me this error, File "loginscript.py", line 11
    subprocess.run(['useradd',input=word , shell=True ])
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shell=True` is doubly wrong; if you were to use it, it should go outside the first argument; but when the first argument is a list, you almost certainly don't want `shell=True` here at all. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

(There *are* situations where `shell=True` make sense with a list argument, but you really need to understand what you are doing. This is slightly less weird on Windows, but only because Windows as a whole is weirder.)

Also, you probably want to omit `input=` in front of the `word` argument, and simply run

```
with open("login.txt",'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.rstrip('\n')
        subprocess.run(['useradd', word], check=True)
```

Finally, notice also how the newline is still present when you read lines like this, and needs to be trimmed off, and how we pass in `check=True` to have Python raise an exception if the subprocess fails.